# Subclassing JavaFX Stage / Scene

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Coming from Swing and being new to JavaFX I tried to subclass Java FX Stages and Scenes. However I quickly run into problems, like the init method not being of my subclassed sceen not being found during the initialization.

So I was wondering: Are Java FX Stages and Sceens to be subclassed like one would subclass JFrames and JPanels in Swing or is this discouraged?

Comment: I long ago stopped subclassing `JFrame` and `JPanel` in the vast majority of my Swing code anyway. Most of the time you can just instantiate the standard classes and call methods; I prefer this approach. That said, there is nothing to stop you subclassing `Stage` and `Scene` if you want, and using that approach. (The only exception might be in the initial `Stage` that is passed to the startup method `Application.start()` by the JavaFX framework; you can ignore that if you want.) What `init()` method are you referring to? `Scene` does not define an `init()` method. Can you post some code?

Comment: Scene has two private init methods, init() and init(double width, double height). They somehow get invoked during the construction. Do you know of any examples where Scene or Stage are subclassed (links etc.)? I try to come up with an example.

Comment: If the methods are private, you can't access them in a subclass. But that doesn't prevent you subclassing `Scene`. See example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass `Scene` and `Stage` and many other FX library classes in pretty much the same way. I'm not sure I'd recommend it, and it doesn't seem to be a style that appears in any of the examples from the official tutorials. (In fact, I long ago stopped using subclasses of `JFrame` and `JPanel` in the vast majority of my swing code, preferring instead more the style in the FX examples.)

But it's certainly possible:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SubclassingExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage defaultStageIgnored) {
        Stage stage = new MyStage();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class MyStackPane extends StackPane{
        public MyStackPane() {
            getChildren().add(new Label("Hello World"));
        }
    }

    public static class MyScene extends Scene {
        public MyScene() {
            super(new MyStackPane(), 250, 75);
        }
    }

    public static class MyStage extends Stage {
        public MyStage() {
            setScene(new MyScene());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned that You stopped using subclasses of `JFrame` and `JPanel` long time ago. Can subclaassing `Stage` and `Scene` can affect the program in some bad way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @olimpiabaku It’s just bad practice to overuse inheritance. You should subclass for the purpose of adding new functionality, not for the purpose of calling specific API methods on a class. If you look at the subclasses in this (anti-)example, all they do is call methods that could be called on an instance of the existing class. It’s much more maintainable to use a creational pattern if some kind, where you write a method that instantiates a scene and stage (in this example) and calls `getChildren().add(...)`, `setScene(...)` etc.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your explanation. I'm writing a JavaFX project now, and my teacher requires us to use MVC model, that's why I thought about subclassing those.